# iMac screen won't turn back on after a sleep session in Windows 8.1

Tags: imac, sleep-wake, screensaver, windows

I do a lot of hardware programming, and some of the chips I write applications for don't have IDEs and/or compilers that are compatible with anything other than windows, so I do use Windows quite often. I have recently decided to dedicate my personal laptop to my main operating system, Linux, and move Windows over to my other computer, iMac. The problem I have been encountering ever since I installed Windows 8.1, though, is that the screen won't turn back on after a sleep session. Has anyone else had a similar problem? How did you overcome it?
Note: I have already set my screensaver time to `none` and that didn't seem to fix anything.

Answer (score -1):

I have a 2011 iMac which I have been having the same issue with since windows 8.  For me, it is an issue with when "turn off the display after..." is set. I have turned off this feature, and my PC just goes into sleep mode instead. It is slightly inconvenient though, as I can't run things in the background during.